# How to lower CPU usage while using iptables NAT

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, wireguard

I have 5 VM's : VM-A,VM-1,VM-2,VM-3,VM-4
I using wireguard to connect VM-A to all other VM's. The traffic transfer rate is around 200Mbps. All the VM's have 5gbps network.
But the CPU is rising to 95%. In this the softirq rises to 60%

I guess it is due to using iptables NAT commands

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i ens3 -p udp --dport 9100 -j DNAT --to 192.168.150.2
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i ens3 -p udp --dport 9101 -j DNAT --to 192.168.151.2
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i ens3 -p udp --dport 9102 -j DNAT --to 192.168.152.2
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i ens3 -p udp --dport 9103 -j DNAT --to 192.168.153.2
```

Is there any other way which can be used instead of iptables which can lower the CPU usage?

T.I.A

Comment: Have you try this: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5039

Comment: @Roid I couldn't understand anything from there :( Its a very old post so never saw it before.